# Optimization problem with complex and real values

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, mathematical-optimization, maximize

I have the following optimization problem:
$\underset{{{a}_{1}},...,{{a}_{m}}}{\mathop{\max }}\,\parallel \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}{{{a}_{n}}}{{\varpi }_{n}}{{e}^{j{{\theta }_{n}}}}{{\varphi }_{n}}{{\parallel }^{2}}$
with constraints
$1\le {{a}_{i}}\le 40,\forall i\in \{1,2,...,m\}$

${{\varpi }_{n}}\in {{\mathbb{C}}} $

${{\varphi }_{n}}\in {{\mathbb{C}}} $

${{\theta }_{n}}$ is an angle

${a}_{n}$ is positive

m<N

${{{a}_{m+1}},...,{{a}_{N}}}=1$

j is imaginary unit

This ia a convex optimization problem?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Is this a Mathematica question? If it is, then please upload Mathematica code that you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: Please post some attempts as Syed suggested, it will help both you and us. Also some notation questions: is the length of $a$ (which is $m$) specified? Also, is $m$ the same as $N$ in this case?

Comment: Also is $j$ a given constant?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, i dont have a mathematica code. The length of a is m correct . i add some analysis.

Comment: i did some changes,  this is correct